# Create a discord bot that only allows a specific word through

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a discord bot that only allows the word "upgrade" through and deletes any other word. I have an almost complete bot working except I want it to be able to also detect multiple times of the word, such as "upgrade upgrade". My two different code versions that I'm working on are as follows:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (!message.content.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase().includes("upgrade")) return 
  message.delete()
});


client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase() != "upgrade") return 
  message.delete()
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What exactly is the *question*? It seems like you have made two separate attempts to solve the problem. **What happens** when you try using these versions of the code? **How is that different** from what is supposed to happen? Finally, *why do you need our help*? What are you hoping we can tell you? Please read [ask] and **ask a question**.

Comment: Yes  thank you, sorry for not making my question clear. When I run the first code, it works except there is a loop hole where as long as "upgrade" is apart of any sentence the bot lets the whole sentence through. Which is not desired.

When I run the second code, it works except it does not allow "upgrade upgrade" through, because in this instance it has to equal exactly to "upgrade". Which is also not desired. 

I was hoping to ask if anyone had a way to alter either of these codes to produce the desired performance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegEx` for validation. Validate only the word 'upgrade':

`if (message.content.toLowerCase().match(/^upgrade ?( upgrade ?){0,}$/)) return;`
Matches with 'upgrade', 'upgrade upgrade', 'upgrade upgrade upgrade' etc.

Validate all sentences starting with the word 'upgrade':

`if (message.content.toLowerCase().match(/^upgrade( .*)?$/)) return;`

Comment: Appreciate the input. I tested this out and "upgrade upgrade" gets deleted which is not desired. Any solution to that?

Comment: @Mike My bad, remove `!` from `if` condition. `if (message.content.toLowerCase().match(/^upgrade ?( upgrade ?){0,}$/)) return;`

Comment: @Mike, I think the messages with the 'upgrade' are deleted in the codes you shared and returned if the message does not contain 'upgrade'.

Comment: Yes that works, but I can’t get it to accept “upgrade upgrade”. The code is looking for only one use of “upgrade” so if it’s typed twice it doesn’t recognize it and deletes it. Haven’t been able to find a solution to this yet.

Comment: @Mike `if (message.content.toLowerCase().match(/^upgrade ?( upgrade ?){0,}$/)) return;` works fine for 'upgrade upgrade'.

Comment: `client.on('message', (message) => { if (message.content.toLowerCase().match(/^upgrade ?( upgrade ?){0,}$/)) return; message.delete();  })`